How to access a boolean in 'const TValue & Value' parameter in C++ FireMonkey TStringGrid::OnDrawColumnCell event?
I am trying to check a boolean value from a boolean column in the FMX TStringGrid::OnDrawColumnCell event.
The callback has the following parameters:
void __fastcall TMainForm::SegmentStringGridDrawColumnCell(TObject *Sender, TCanvas * const Canvas, TColumn * const Column,
      const TRectF &Bounds, const int Row, const TValue &Value, const TGridDrawStates State)

If I try and read Value.AsBoolean I get the following error:

[bcc64x Error] main.cpp(235): 'this' argument to member function 'AsBoolean' has type 'const System::Rtti::TValue', but function is not marked const

If I try and declare a non-const TValue and assign it to the const TValue:
    TValue MyValue;
    #ifndef __clang__
      MyValue = TValue::_op_Implicit(Value);
    #else
      MyValue = TValue::From(Value);
    #endif
    bool myVal = MyValue.AsBoolean();

The code compiles and links, but at runtime I get the following exception:

exception class EInvalidCast with message 'Invalid class typecast'

The exception occurs when I try to access MyValue.AsBoolean().
How do I access the value from const TValue &Value?

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating how exactly your are trying to access the value. In any case, the EInvalidCast implies the TValue does not hold a boolean to begin with

Hello Remy, I have added the one line of code where I simply try to assign to a boolean.  If I breakpoint on this line MyValue says it is stores AsUByte.  How do I get this value?  It displays as false in the default draw and if I try AsInteger that also gives the same exception.  Can you at least confirm that I am copying the value to a non const TValue correctly?  I cannot directly access any of the fields from the passed TValue (Value) as it is const and the compiler complains the function is not marked const.

I found that I needed to simplify how I copied from the const TValue to a local variable so I could access the contents without getting the error regards Value being const but function not.
This code did not make MyValue = Value, it changed it to a "tkRecord" type.
TValue MyValue;
#ifndef __clang__
  MyValue = TValue::_op_Implicit(Value);
#else
  MyValue = TValue::From(Value);
#endif
bool myVal = MyValue.AsBoolean();

All I actually needed to do was simply copy the value into my own variable.
Then I could access the Kind and determine what type the TValue is.
TValue MyValue = Value;
System::Typinfo::TTypeKind Kind = MyValue.Kind;

In my case I found Kind was "tkString", once I knew this, I was able to do a string compare to determine the boolean value "True" and "False".

Regarding the error about TValue's methods not being marked const, I would suggest filing a bug report with Embarcadero about that. In the meantime, you can use const_cast instead of making a local copy, as the original TValue being passed to the event is not a const object. For example: TTypeKind Kind = const_cast<TValue&>(Value).Kind;

Bug report filed
